# Convert tif image to txt or csv file

Tags: image

I would like to simply convert a grayscale tif file to a text file, in which the numbers in a 2-dimensional array represent the gray values of each pixel, e.g. the result should be:

```
{
{10,11,14,8,9},
{11,9,15,12,10},
{12,4,7,8,4}
}
```

with the numbers representing the gray values. I tried with Raster, but this did not work.

Comment: Look up ImageData

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty simple. First import the image.

```
img = Import[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "moon.tiff"}]]
```

Then export it as byte data (integers in the range 0 - 255).

```
Export[
  FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "moon.csv"}], 
  ImageData[img, "Byte"]]
```